# Poner variable en nombre de listas para poder usar un for, en julia

Tags: variables, bucle-for, julia

Tal vez sea una pregunta muy simple, peo me gustaría saber si hay una forma de poner en el nombre de una lista una variable, para poder llamar a la lista con un for, con este ejemplo debería quedar más claro

```
x_1=[1,2]  
x_2=[2,3]  

for i=1:2  
      println(x_i)  
end
```

Lo que yo quisiera es que me imprimiera la lista `x_1` y seguido la lista `x_2`, este código te dice que `x_i` no está definido, así que ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que de hecho lo que esta definido se llama `x_1` y `x_2` no `x_i`. Entonces para llamar a `x_1` o `x_2`, dentro del `for` podrías pegar el texto  "`x_"` con el valor de `i` con `string`. Luego usar la función de `eval` con `Meta.parse` para evaluar un texto como código. Algo como esto:

```
x_1=[1,2]  
x_2=[2,3]  

for i=1:2  
      println(eval(Meta.parse(string("x_",i))))
end
```